# routes with the same resource multiple times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, rails-routing

I have a model Examples which has_many :users but also belongs_to a Group. I want to have an index of both just examples and another index of group examples. like- url.com/examples(should only show examples without a group_id) and url.com/group/1/examples. currently my routes file looks like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

resources :groups do
  resources :examples
end

resources :examples
```

but as I am sure you know this creates a problem because the index action is the same causing all of the Examples to show up on both url.com/examples and url.com/groups/1/examples.

I have searched and searched and searched for an answer on this but for some reason I cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check in `before_filter` in `examples_controller` if you came there from nested route and set controller's behavior accordingly. For example:

```
class ExamplesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_group, if: -> { params[:group_id].present? }
  def index
    @examples = if @group
                  @group.examples
                else
                  Example.where(group_id: nil)
                end
  end
  # ...
  private
  def set_group
    @group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
  end
end
```

Comment: For some reason they are still showing up on both /examples and /groups/1/examples

Comment: okay I threw @group = Group.find(params[:group_id]) into the index action and it helped a little bit, now in the .com/groups/1/examples it is only showing the group created example but in the .com/examples it is still showing all of them.

Comment: @DylanLittle I thought `/examples` should show all of examples. What is the desired behavior?

Comment: sorry. I meant that /examples should only show examples that arent under a group. or in other words where(group_id: nil)

Comment: @DylanLittle I edited my answer accordingly. All you need to do is add `where(group_id: nil)` scope.